# STL copy works without algorithm library?

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl, copy

I just have a question regarding the algorithm library. Why is it that i can use the copy algorithm in my code if I do not have #include algorithm? I am really just curious as to why this is. Thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
//#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> intList;
    vector<string> stringList;

    intList.push_back(13);
    intList.push_back(12);
    intList.push_back(77);

    stringList.push_back("Hello");
    stringList.push_back("Bye");
    stringList.push_back("Greetings");

    ostream_iterator<int> screen1(cout, " ");
    ostream_iterator<string> screen2(cout, " ");

    copy(intList.begin(), intList.end(), screen1);
    cout << endl;
    copy(stringList.begin(), stringList.end(), screen2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the preprocessor on your code, and seeing if <algorithm> was indirectly being included? If you haven't done that yet, why not?

Comment: I am assuming it does that because i run it without <algorithm> and it runs fine. I am just curious as to why and how?

Comment: The short answer is that any standard header is allowed (but not required) to include any other standard header.

Comment: You can answer both of your questions, yourself, by examining the output of the preprocessor, and figuring it out, by yourself, where the dependency comes from.